# How to block when the ball is over the net?

Tags: rules, volleyball

Can player B touch the ball in any of these situastions?
The ball is traveling to the opponents field after receive. Setter A is close to the ball.
Blocker B is not putting their hands over the net in any of these situations.

[image: volleyball 1]

[image: set3]

Answer (score 1):

The most important rule here is [Rule 9, "Playing the ball"](http://www.fivb.org/EN/Refereeing-Rules/documents/FIVB-Volleyball_Rules_2017-2020-EN-v06.pdf):

> Each team must play within its own playing area and space

As such, B is perfectly entitled to play the ball as shown in both your diagrams. In your top diagram, A is *also* entitled to play the part of the ball which is on their side of the net - this could lead to a simultaneous contact which is covered by Rule 9.1.2 if you want the details.

In your second diagram, A is playing the ball outside their own playing area, so will commit a fault if they actually touch the ball (or player B). Quoting Rule 11.4.1, which lists the faults a player may commit at the net:

> A player touches the ball or an opponent in the opponent's space
>   before or during the opponent’s attack hit.